# How to split a string in python by certain characters?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am trying to solve a problem with prefix notation, but I am stuck on the part, where I want to split my string into an array:
If I have the input `+22 2` I want to get the array to look like this:`['+', '22', '2']`
I tried using the

```
import re
```

function, but I am not sure how it works.
I tried the

```
word.split(' ')
```

method, but it only helps with the spaces.. any ideas?
P.S:
In the prefix notation I will also have + - and *.
So I need to split the string so the space is not in the array, and +, -, * is in the array
I am thinking of

```
word = input()
array = word.split(' ')
```

Then after that I am thinking of splitting a string by these 3 characters.

Sample input:
`'+-12 23*67 1'`

Output:
`['+', '-', '12', '23', '*', '67', '1']`

Comment: Are all of your "words" in the exact same pattern - a `+` at the front, then some digits, then a space, then more digits?

Comment: My input is in a prefix notation, so it is like: +-21 24*23 12

Comment: @Norbi could you provide some sample inputs in your question

Comment: OK, that's a **lot** more complicated than your original question...

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/5307218/1426065

Comment: The part where I do the prefix notation is alright, I have only problems every time with the input...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `re` to find patterns in text, it seems you are looking for either one of these: `+`, `-` and `*` or a digit group. So compile a pattern that looks for that and find all that match this pattern and you will get a list:

```py
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'([-+*]|\d+)')

string = '+-12 23*67 1'
array = pattern.findall(string)
print(array)

# Output:
# ['+', '-', '12', '23', '*', '67', '1']
```

Also a bit of testing (comparing your sample strings with the expected output):

```py
test_cases = {
    '+-12 23*67 1': ['+', '-', '12', '23', '*', '67', '1'],
    '+22 2': ['+', '22', '2']
}

for string, correct in test_cases.items():
    assert pattern.findall(string) == correct

print('Tests completed successfully!')
```

Pattern explanation (you can read about this in the docs linked below):
`r'([-+*]|\d+)'`
`r` in front to make it a raw string so that Python interprets all the characters literally, this helps with escape sequences in the regex pattern because you can escape them with one backslash
`(...)` parentheses around (they are not necessary in this case) indicate a group which can later be retrieved if needed (but in this case they don't matter much)
`[...]` indicates that any single character from this group can be matched so it will match if any of `-`, `+` and `*` will be present
`|` logical `or`, meaning that can match either side (to differentiate between numbers and special characters in this case)
`\d` special escape sequence for digits, meaning to match any digit, the `+` there indicates matching any one or more digits

Useful:

- [`re` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html), the docs there explain what each character in the pattern does